# Firewall rules for using mtr/traceroute from LAN

Tags: linux, firewall, networking, mtr

I have a LAN of Linux computers that get access to the Internet over NAT.
The gateway runs a restrictive firewall.
I have ICMP echo requests and replies allowed to pass through the firewall on the gateway, so I can ping any external host from a LAN computer, but mtr and traceroute to an external host hang at the gateway hop.

What additional firewall rules should I have so these tools would work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux traceroute uses UDP by default, on a random high port, while Windows tracert uses ICMP.  For your Linux machines, you'll either need to configure the firewall to allow UDP on high ports, or use the -I commandline switch to specify the use of ICMP ECHO instead of UDP datagrams.

Edited to add:
By default, it picks a random port in the unassigned ports range, commonly referred to as "high ports".  Typically this means a port in the 49152–65535 range (see [this port list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)).  The man page refers to this as an "unlikely value" for a service to be running on inadvertently, since we don't actually want the host to process the UDP datagrams as information.  If you want, you can specify the port with -p, but be aware that it will increment the destination port by 1 with each probe when using UDP.  If you want to use a constant port, specify the -U switch (default port is 53 for this).  Alternatively, if you don't want to use UDP or ICMP, you can use the -T switch to specify TCP SYN mode, which will use a constant port that you can set with -p.  Then you would open that port on your firewall.

Only UDP is allowed for unprivileged users.

Comment: I assume "high ports" is supposed to mean a certain port range, is this documented somewhere?

Comment: See my edit.  You can look up the traceroute man page if you want to know more.

Comment: Thanks, traceroute -I did the trick, I also had to allow ICMP "time exceeded" (type 11) in my firewall (I had only ICMP echo requests and replies allowed as I stated in my question).
I've also read the man page for traceroute one more time and I couldn't find anything about a -T switch there. May I know what OS do you use and what version of traceroute do you use, just for general knowledge?

Comment: I'm using traceroute version 2.0.9, Nov 19 2007, on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS.